# importing the same module in several places

Tags: python

So I am curious here from the standpoint of efficiency. Hows does this work:

Say I have the following script:

```
#home.py

import os

def homePrinter():
    print os.environ["HOME"]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    homePrinter()
```

Simple, I import the module and then run the `homePrinter()` command which runs `os.environ["HOME"]`.

but then lets say that I save that script as `home.py` and run it from within the following script:

```
#path.py

import os
print os.environ["PATH"]

import home
home.homePrinter()
```

Now when I run the `path.py` file, it imports os and when I import `home.py` it also imports os. How does python handle the same module being imported twice?

Answer (score 3):

Python puts every import in `sys.modules` so the next time you try to import it will simply get the imported module from `sys.modules` instead of re-reading the file.

Here's an example:

**eggs.py**

```
import sys

print 'Importing spam'
import spam
print

print 'Importing spam again'
import spam
print

print 'Removing spam from sys.modules and importing again'
del sys.modules['spam']
import spam
```

**spam.py**

```
print 'this is spam'
```

Output:

```
Importing spam
this is spam

Importing spam again

Removing spam from sys.modules and importing again
this is spam
```